# SQL Server De-duplication Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, duplication

I have a table that contains columns of Country, City, Location, Description. Due to the size of the description field it's not possible to bind the four fields into a composite key to prevent duplication. I have been trying to prevent duplication by way of a trigger but no matter what I try it rolls back every insert, including inserts of unique data.

```
IF Exists ( Select      a.*
            From        [dbo].[Table] a
                JOIN    Inserted b
                    on  a.Country = b.Country
                    and a.City = b.City
                    and a.Location = b.Location
                    and ltrim(rtrim(a.Description)) = ltrim(rtrim(b.Description))
            )


    BEGIN
        Raiserror   ('The description that you are trying to load already exists.', 16, 1)
        Rollback 
    END
```

Does anybody have any ideas what is wrong with the above, and what changes I need to make in order to get it to only roll back duplicate inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using an `AFTER INSERT` trigger (if you don't specify something else triggers are the `AFTER` type, give the full code for your trigger definition for us to be sure) so this is expected: your trigger fires *after* the insert so it will always see the row you have just put in.

Instead of `IF EXISTS ...` you could instead do `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) > 1` which will check to see if your new row(s) bring the total to more than one.

You could also use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger which might be a little more efficient (doing less work that you later rollback) though I doubt the difference will be significant unless you have a *very* insert-heavy workload on that table with lots of duplicates.

Two side points:
Firstly make sure you deal with `UPDATES` as well or you could get duplicates in that way too.
Secondly, make sure what you are doing is actually worthwhile: trying to enforce data integrity on free-text entry fields like "description" is generally a lost cause. You could have two entries that are identical apart from one having a double space or spelling error, and your check won't pick them out as equivalent.

Comment: I didn't even know "INSTEAD OF INSERT" was an option. I've hooked that up and I'm raising the error with an ELSE, works perfectly now. Thanks for your help. 

Edit: By the way, I understand what you're saying about the double spaces and full stops etc, I'd already considered running a replace on double spaces but this isn't a critical system and I have an SSRS report hooked up to the table so the end user can see what already exists in the table, this is just an extra step to alleviate some obvious duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition you are checking will always be true as for every insert query executed there will be an entry in the `dbo.Table` and `inserted` as well so it will rollback the transaction.

From MSDN

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

I would advice you to check the duplicate before insert as

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select a.* FROM [dbo].[Table] a WHERE..............)
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] .......
```

More Readings : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't seem to work, instead it was letting all transactions through and never threw the trigger. There's an answer further down that mentioned an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER which did the trick.